# Django. Sanity and understandable one-to-one relationships

Tags: python, django, orm, one-to-one

I am wondering how to make the one-to-one relations in Django a bit more understandable and clear for the new developers.
Let's take a look at the basic example of the Django docs.

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s the place" % self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(
        Place,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s the restaurant" % self.place.name

class Waiter(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s the waiter at %s" % (self.name, self.restaurant) 

What follows are examples of operations that can be performed using the Python API facilities.

Create a couple of Places:

>>> p1 = Place(name='Demon Dogs', address='944 W. Fullerton')
>>> p1.save()
>>> p2 = Place(name='Ace Hardware', address='1013 N. Ashland')
>>> p2.save()
Create a Restaurant. Pass the ID of the “parent” object as this object’s ID:

>>> r = Restaurant(place=p1, serves_hot_dogs=True, serves_pizza=False)
>>> r.save()

A Restaurant can access its place:

>>> r.place
<Place: Demon Dogs the place>
A Place can access its restaurant, if available:

>>> p1.restaurant
<Restaurant: Demon Dogs the restaurant>
```

The problem that I don't understand how to let the First model to *know* and *show* about the Second model.

So when I see the Place model, I don't have any idea that it should contain the *restaurant* property later. This property will be assigned by Restaurant oneToOne field relation.

So is there exist any *official* django way to *annotate* | let the developer know somehow that some model will be linked to another model later to know about new properties?
Or should I just only use the comments etc.?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When you make a OneToOneField reference, that's a special case of a foreign key relationship.  That relationship is defined in the database as a foreign key for the second table which links back to the first.  Given this, how would you approach a better way of demonstrating the relationship between `Place` and `Restaurant`?

Comment: I think that if the dev cares about Restaurant model dev will know about Place and the corresponding property in Place objects. It is also arguable that a Place can apply to many different models and the idea of explicit association with them from the Place side does not make sense (it is duplicating the relations without need and you don't know what future models will need a place). Wait for betteranswers but @Jason comment is already explicit on how this reflects relations in the database, and the ER Model used there.

Comment: jason and progmatico thanks for the answer guys. I know how it works at the DB level and in the case of Django as well. But I just wondered if there are exists any possibility to make some annotation to make it explicit. Based on your answers I see that it isn't possible and we should check the DB or UML of the DB relations etc. and based on it we'll know that our models will have a property or linked model regarding Django ORM. Please, fix me if I'm wrong.

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand it but to be honest it's very surprising for me because, for example, in the case of Doctrine (php ORM) there is existing such possibly
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional

Answer (score 0):

So regarding @jason and @progmatico answers and the official Django documentation, I assume that making some annotation in the First Model about the Second one isn't possible. 
I know it's fine regarding DB relation principles etc. I don't want to say that this Django feature is bad or good.

The fact that we can't annotate somehow the First Model about Future Second Model relations was very surprising for me because, for example, in the case of Doctrine (PHP ORM) there is existing such possibility

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional